# When is it best to use a switch statement in PHP?

Tags: php

In what circumstances should I be using a switch statement rather than if statements in PHP?

Comment: For what it's worth, this really applies to any language with a `switch` equivalent.

Comment: In C, a switch statement can be much faster than an if statement in some cases. You don't have that advantage in PHP.

Comment: @jtbandes, Sjoerd: Performance is probably the least of OP's concerns here though :)

Comment: Good info in the manual - http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Answer (score 3):

Never.

- You will forget the break statement at the end of a case, which can lead to undesired results.
- You can only evaluate one condition, an else-if is more versatile.
- It is ugly.

That said, sometimes you specifically need the fall-through functionality, or you return from the function in every case statement so that you can not forget the break. Maybe that warrants an exception.

Comment: Huh? Why is this -3? This is the most correct answer in here. PHP `switch` has a weird `continue` and it does "loose comparisons", which basically makes the PHP `switch` different from every other language out there. It offers no performance bonus, either. Don't use it in PHP.

Comment: -1:  You should catch any missing breaks during testing.  There are times you only need to test one item.  IMO, a bunch of if-elses are uglier than a switch.

Comment: In the future, even if you're right, it is hard to take seriously answers that start with a dramatic imperative.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using a `switch` statement when you have a sequence of `if`s just testing one variable for different values. The switch statement is really just used to make your code look cleaner and be more clear, so if you feel like it does that, use it - your gut is probably right.

Answer (score 2):

Switch should be used when you have a series of related conditionals that can be isolated logically or if you have a series of conditions that have to be executed based on the state or result of a singular variable or expression.

Contrary to other answers, the expression in the switch does not need to be isolated to a single variable (though it's simpler, easier to read, and generally a good idea), but the case statements need to generate individual results from the evaluated expression(s).

A good rule of thumb is to use switches when you have an easy to ready expression that will generate multiple results that you must then execute logic based upon. If your expressions are unrelated, result in boolean conditions only, or become complex/related (like if a then b, if c then b, if d then a sometimes b), then stick with ifs.

Answer (score 1):

You use a switch when a certain variable could be one of many different "cases"  In an IF statement, you could substitute this method with multiple ELSE IFs and very long conditionals if you needed.

There really isn't an easy way to answer this as there isn't a best time to use a switch.  It is only when you show code that someone can say "That would work better with a switch."  Still, in the end, you may only save a few milliseconds.