# What is the alternative of using several elseif nested loops in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, switch-statement

What is the best alternative of using several (23 in my case) `if-elseif` nested loops in PHP?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: Why don't you show what you have? Sometimes, there is a pattern or two that you can skip and not have 23 cases by simply changing a bit of logic. More often than not, developers will do a bunch of unnecessary repetition.

Comment: If you're setting the same variable in that if-elseif chain then you can either use a hashmap to map the relationships or use a ternary operator. You'll need to post your script for us to determine the best optimization route.

Comment: This really depends on the conditions you have inside those clauses; a switch is possible, but not always the right choice. We need to see the code in question.

Comment: btw, `if - elseif` are not nested, it is one structure

Comment: What *is* an "`if-elseif` nested loop"? These are statements, not loops.

Answer (score 4):

If **performance** is your concern, `if` statements use *check* followed by a *jump* to the next clause where as in a `switch`  the value is loaded first, compared and iterated through the value table to find a match, which is faster in most cases.

For **readability** I think `switch` is better when you have more than two conditions.

**But primarily everything depends on the usage circumstance.**

**If you are in doubt of which to choose**:

- Choose `switches` when you have an easy to read expression that will
  generate multiple results that you must then execute logic based
  upon.
- If your expressions are unrelated, result in boolean conditions only,
  or become complex/related (like `if` a `then` b, `if` c `then` b,   `if` d `then` a sometimes b), then stick with ifs. (As said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452544/when-is-it-best-to-use-a-switch-statement-in-php))

Comment: A switch statement doesn't behave differently from if-elseif chains; they're effectively the same thing, provided that case(s) have break statements.

Comment: @Ja͢ck Yes in PHP I guess, but dont they behave differently in Java and C.

Answer (score 0):

The switch statement will do it.
http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php