# Why are nested loops considered as inefficient and bad design in code? What is the better alternative of nested loops?

Tags: java, hashmap, nested-loops, scalability

The question relates to another question (link given in comment), which suggests using switch statements, but in my case, I believe using the switch statement is not applicable.

I've written some Java code which converts a phone number (123456789) to corresponding English words (one two three four five six seven eight nine).

This Java program also identifies the double and triple consecutive occurrences of the numbers. In such a case, the first occurrence will be read as an individual number, followed by a *"double"* or *"triple"* occurrence of a number. For example, the number `"1 2 222"` will be read as `"one two triple two"`.

```
public class DigitToWord {

    public static Map<String, String> map;

    static {
        Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<>();
        result.put("0", "zero");
        result.put("1", "one");
        result.put("2", "two");
        result.put("3", "three");
        result.put("4", "four");
        result.put("5", "five");
        result.put("6", "six");
        result.put("7", "seven");
        result.put("8", "eight");
        result.put("9", "nine");
        map = result;
    }

    public static String convertNumberToWords(String n) {
        String result = "";
        for(int i=0; i<n.length(); i++) {
            String w = Character.toString(n.charAt(i));
            String d = map.get(w) + " ";
            if( (i < n.length()-2)  &&  ((Character.toString(n.charAt(i+1)).equals(w))  &&  (Character.toString(n.charAt(i+2)).equals(w))) ) {
                result = result + d + "double " + d;
                i += 2;
            } else if( (i < n.length()-1)  &&  (Character.toString(n.charAt(i+1)).equals(w)) ) {
                result = result + " double " + d;
                i += 1;
            } else {
                result = result + d;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Here are the problems I believe are worth discussing:

**Question 1**. Why is this considered a bad design, due to these nested loops (especially for production code)? What is the better alternative to nested loops?

**Question 2**. How do we make this code scalable, If we add more functionality to this program?

The explanation for Q2: For instance, if there are four consecutive numbers, print 'quadruple'. If five consecutive numbers, print 'quintuple'. If six consecutive numbers, print 'sextuplet'.

My naive approach, to solve Q2 is to write another function to print 'quadruple', a separate function to print 'quintuple', another function to print 'sextuplet', and so on.

This approach sounds pretty old-fashioned and ineffective though I'm open to your feedback and suggestions which I believe might help me improve.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31198241/what-is-the-alternative-of-using-several-elseif-nested-loops-in-php

Comment: The above link discusses the related question to some extent, but I only see using SWITCH statements as an answer.

Comment: Due to *what* nested loops? There is only one loop in your code. And where did you get the idea that nested loops are considered inefficient?

Comment: @user207421 For your first question, I'm well aware that there is just ONE loop, I've used several in my actual code but I skipped them in my question for the sake of simplicity. If you read the entire question that might help you understand my point.

Secondly, when you're given with such a problem by your employer/recruiter, they do not want Just solution, but how efficient your code is and how many possible ways you come up with for solving the problem. (FYI, my fellow-coders got better solution than my code and I'll get to know HOW sooner or later.)
Thank you for your downvote :-)

Comment: When you post a question about loops it is rather pointless not to include code that exhibits them. You haven't answered my second question in any way.

Comment: NB You have no information about downvoting, and no business guessing about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is this considered a bad design, due to these nested loops (especially for production code)?

Nested loops are NOT "bad design" *per se*.

Nested loops *may be* an inefficient solution, and there *may be* a better solution.  On the other hand, they *may not be* a better solution.  (Aside: inefficient solution is not necessarily a bad design.  It depends on the impact of the inefficiency on other things, and on your priorities.)

Consider the following:

```
String[][] lotsOfStrings = new String[N][N];

// Populate the above from a file

// Find "fred"
boolean found = false;
for (int i = 0; i < N && !found; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < N && !found; j++) {
        found = "fred".equals(lotsOfStrings[i][j]);
    }
}
```

This is a nested loop.  But it is not inefficient.  Indeed trying to avoid a nested loop here will result in non-idiomatic code that is most likely less efficient than the above, especially after it has been optimized by the Java JIT compiler.

> What is the better alternative to nested loops?

There is not general answer to that.  It depends on the problem you are trying to solve.

The previous example doesn't have a "better" solution, IMO.  No matter how you do it, you must test `N^2` strings before you can decide that `"fred"` is missing.  (It makes no different if you use a nested loop or some other way to iterate them all.)

You might be able to tweak it to make it *slightly* faster.  But spending a lot of effort writing a proper performance test, tweaking, testing, tweaking, testing ... is probable not worth the effort.

But in other cases ...

Suppose that we need to find if a **huge** array of strings contains any duplicates.  The simple solution is:

```
String[] lotsOfStrings = new String[N];

// Populate the above from a file

// Test for duplicates
boolean duplicates = false;
for (int i = 0; i < N && !duplicates; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < N && !duplicates; j++) {
        duplicates = lotsOfStrings[i].equals(lotsOfStrings[j]);
    }
}
```

That is going to perform `N * (N + 1) / 2` comparisons, where `N` is the number of strings.  (It has complexity `O(N^2)`)

A more sophisticated solution is this:

```
String[] lotsOfStrings = new String[N];
// Populate the above from a file

// Test for duplicates
Set<String> seen = new HashSet<>();
boolean duplicates = false;
for (int i = 0; i < N && !duplicates; i++) {
    duplicates = !seen.add(lotsOfStrings[i]);
}
```

That is is only going to perform `N` add operations, and `add` on a `HashSet` is `O(1)` (amortized).  So the above is going to be a lot faster ... when `N` is large.  (But it will be slower for really small values of `N` because of the overheads in creating a `HashSet` and adding objects to it.)

> How do we make this code scalable; e.g. to support "triple", "quadruple", "quintuple" etcetera.

Well that is actually an example where nested loops provide a simple AND efficient solution.  Something like this:

```
public static Map<Integer, String> map2;

static {
    Map<Integer, String> result = new HashMap<>();
    result.put(2, "double");
    result.put(3, "triple");
    result.put(4, "quadruple");
    // ...
    map = result;
}


public static String convertNumberToWords(String n) {
    String result = "";
    for(int i=0; i<n.length(); i++) {
        String w = Character.toString(n.charAt(i));
        String d = map.get(w) + " ";
        int count = 1;
        while (count + i < n.length) {
            if (n.charAt(i) == n.charAt(i + count)) {
                count++;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (count > 1) {
            result = result + " " + map2.get(count) + " " + d;
            i = i + count - 1;
        } else {
            result = result + " " + d;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Note, that there are a few problems (and bugs, I think) in your original version, but in the interests of (my!) time, I won't point them out.

---

Finally, I should point out that unless you are translating phone numbers with hundreds of digits, or millions of phone numbers, the efficiency of this code is most likely NOT RELEVANT.

And the performance difference between using `switch` versus using a `Map` is going to be too small to be relevant, unless you are processing vast numbers of phone number translations.

An inefficient solution is not necessarily a bad solution.

---

> Secondly, when you're given with such a problem by your employer/recruiter, they do not want Just solution, but how efficient your code is and how many possible ways you come up with for solving the problem.

Well yes.  But what they really want to know is if you are capable of **recognizing** when a problem **could** be solved more efficiently.  (Assuming that they are not clueless.  Clueless recruiters are a problem.)  And for that, you need to do better than "nested loops are bad".  This is why a good CS degree has a 1 or 2 units on Data Structures and Algorithms ... which teach the student (among other things) how to do complexity analysis, and how to optimize code *scientifically*.

Comment: Thank you, Stephen C. Your detailed answer really helped me understanding some nuts and bolts.